# zf2: Nesting View Models Issue

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to create a nested view model with `zf2`.

I am using standard `zf2` skeleton application.

in my `IndexController`:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('application/index/index.phtml');

    $aboutView = new ViewModel();
    $aboutView->setTemplate('application/index/about.phtml'); //standard html

    $view->addChild($aboutView, 'about');

    return $view;
}
```

In my `layout.phtml`, I added the following code:

HTML code:

```
echo $this->content
```

HTML code:

```
echo $this->about;
```

The nested view is not showing in the result. When `var_dump($this->about)`, I am getting `NULL.`

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to render `about` inside `layout.phtml`? but you attach it to `index.phtml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using it correctly.

**layout.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * $view will be assigned to this, with the template index.phtml
 */
echo $this->content
```

$aboutView will only be assigned to the ViewModel named $view as a child. To access this you will need to use index.phtml

**index.phtml**

```
<?php 
/**
 * This will have the content from about.phtml
 */
var_dump($this->about)
```

If you want to assign a ViewModel to the actual base ViewModel (which uses layout.phtml) you can access it via layout:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $aboutView = new ViewModel();
    $aboutView->setTemplate('application/index/about.phtml'); //standard html
    $this->layout()->addChild($aboutView, 'about');

    //$this->layout() will return the ViewModel for the layout :)
    //you can now access $this->about inside your layout.phtml view file.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. for your answer it did work. my aim was to assign new variable to the layout.

Comment: public function indexAction()
    {
        $layout = $this->layout();

        //About section
        $aboutView = new ViewModel();
        $aboutView->setTemplate('application/index/about');
        $layout->addChild($aboutView, 'about');

        $view = new ViewModel();
        return $view;
    }